# CurrencyManager prevents hiding a row in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, datagrid, currencymanager

I don't know exactly what Currencymanager is for. I have not explicitly implemented it but it prevents me from hiding rows in my datagrid.

I build the datagrid from a csv file with several columns. One of them includes a double amount (price).

When i want to set all Rows with an amount lower/greater than something to Invisible

```
public override void Execute(object o) {
    DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)o;
    if ((string)Value == "off") row.Visible = false;                       
}
```

it tells me like

```
"Could not hide Rows bounded to the Currency Manager"
```

**The error doesnt appear when i hide a row based on another column data type for ex strings - only if the value is a double.**

Edit: Ii temporarily solved the issue by just catching the InvalidOperationException and ignoring it. It executes anyway. But i think its not good manner :S

Can I somehow remove the bond to the currency manager?

Comment: No Code Sample or Line which is throwing error?

Comment: Check out this link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/using-currency-manager-to-bind-data

Comment: Most people would use a DataView and/or RowFilter to control what shows to the user

Comment: The DataTable finally get placed into a DataGridView so i thought it should also work :$ But it "works" anyway, maybe the exception doestn matter that much. Have **you** deleted my last comment? :P

Comment: This approach is slow, you may want to look at `DataView` and its `RowFilter` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach is very slow (alternatively you can check the `DataView` and its `RowFilter` property), but the fix to your problem is to get the currency manager object of DataGridView and calling `SuspendBinding` and `ResumeBinding` before and after your code.

```
CurrencyManager manager = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource];
manager.SuspendBinding();

//your code goes here
//....

manager.ResumeBinding();
```

Comment: This is very slow, is there an alternative?